Internal load balancing between replicas of a stateful app with consistent session based on HTTP request headers
I have a Statefulset app in my cluster that has 2 replica and I want to Load Balance requests between these two. But I want persistent session based on a header in Http request. for example $http_my_header. also this Http request is created inside cluster with manager app (traffic should go from manager microservice to one these replica based on header). what is the best solution to achieve this ?
I have tried to use kuber Ingress nginx but since my traffic is internal I couldn't send request from manager pod to ingress.
I'm looking for a good solution with minimum complexity added to cluster.
